# Error building a SqlPredicate collection result in Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to perform a simple search operation on the a map using Hazelcast SqlPredicate. It seem to run into some error which I am unable to resolve. Here is the sample program that I used against Hazelcast Cloud.

The program connects to the cluster confirms the connection successfully by getting my test key value pair. Then when I apply a SQLPredicate it throws a error. I currently only days old in Hazelcast therefore not sure what is going wrong in my code.

```
    package com.bsfi.java.client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient;
import com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.discovery.HazelcastCloudDiscovery;
import com.hazelcast.client.spi.properties.ClientProperty;
import com.hazelcast.config.GroupConfig;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.core.IMap;
import com.hazelcast.query.SqlPredicate;

import java.io.Serializable;

class SampleHazelObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String schemaName;
    private String sourceId;
    private String sourceData;
    private String timestamp;

    public SampleHazelObject(String schemaName, String sourceId, String sourceData, String timestamp) {
        this.sourceId = sourceId;
        this.schemaName = schemaName; 
        this.sourceData = sourceData;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getSourceId() {
        return sourceId;
    }

    public void setSourceId(String sourceId) {
        this.sourceId = sourceId;
    }

    public String getSchemaName() {
        return schemaName;
    }

    public void setSchemaName(String schemaName) {
        this.schemaName = schemaName;
    }

    public String getSourceData() {
        return sourceData;
    }

    public void setSourceData(String sourceData) {
        this.sourceData = sourceData;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }




}


public class ErrorDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String clusterName = "hazelhack";
        String  clusterPassword = "XXXXXXXXXX";
        String discoveryToken = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        config.setGroupConfig(new GroupConfig(clusterName, clusterPassword));
        config.setProperty("hazelcast.client.statistics.enabled","true");
        config.setProperty(ClientProperty.HAZELCAST_CLOUD_DISCOVERY_TOKEN.getName(), discoveryToken);
        config.setProperty(HazelcastCloudDiscovery.CLOUD_URL_BASE_PROPERTY.getName(), "https://coordinator.hazelcast.cloud");
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
        IMap<String, SampleHazelObject> mapEntity = client.getMap("SchemaEntity");

        //      Adding a key value here
        mapEntity.put("keytest", new SampleHazelObject("Entity","9999999999","test data",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())));

        System.out.println("Data....: "+mapEntity.get("keytest").getSourceId());
        if(mapEntity.get("keytest").getSourceId().equals("9999999999")) {
            System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
            System.out.println("Now, `map` as one Entity data.");
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Connection failed, check your configuration.");
        }

    // Writing completed. Let us try some lookup and querying on the data
    Collection<SampleHazelObject> objHazelList = mapEntity.values(new SqlPredicate("SourceId = '9999999999'" ));

    for(SampleHazelObject hazelObj:  objHazelList) {
    System.out.println("value=" + hazelObj.getSourceData());
    }

    }

}



    class loader for SampleHazelObject : sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
Oct 23, 2019 7:00:37 AM com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelhack] [3.12.2] A non-empty group password is configured for the Hazelcast client. Starting with Hazelcast version 3.11, clients with the same group name, but with different group passwords (that do not use authentication) will be accepted to a cluster. The group password configuration will be removed completely in a future release.
Oct 23, 2019 7:00:38 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientInvocationService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelhack] [3.12.2] Running with 2 response threads, dynamic=false
Oct 23, 2019 7:00:38 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelhack] [3.12.2] HazelcastClient 3.12.2 (20190802 - e34b163) is STARTING
Oct 23, 2019 7:00:38 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelhack] [3.12.2] HazelcastClient 3.12.2 (20190802 - e34b163) is STARTED
Oct 23, 2019 7:00:38 AM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnectorService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelhack] [3.12.2] Trying to connect to cluster with name: hazelhack
Oct 23, 2019 7:00:40 AM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnectorService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelhack] [3.12.2] Trying to connect to [100.103.97.104]:31629 as owner member
Oct 23, 2019 7:00:42 AM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelhack] [3.12.2] Setting ClientConnection{alive=true, connectionId=1, channel=NioChannel{/192.168.0.104:50119->/3.92.127.167:31629}, remoteEndpoint=[100.103.97.104]:31629, lastReadTime=2019-10-23 07:00:42.092, lastWriteTime=2019-10-23 07:00:41.690, closedTime=never, connected server version=3.12.2} as owner with principal ClientPrincipal{uuid='19d729c6-99c9-4a0e-8a5d-69e6e69c4d4c', ownerUuid='ff72f0dc-664e-4b81-876f-3f4be292136d'}
Oct 23, 2019 7:00:42 AM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelhack] [3.12.2] Authenticated with server [100.103.97.104]:31629, server version:3.12.2 Local address: /192.168.0.104:50119
Oct 23, 2019 7:00:42 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientMembershipListener
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelhack] [3.12.2] 

Members [1] {
    Member [100.103.97.104]:31629 - ff72f0dc-664e-4b81-876f-3f4be292136d
}

Oct 23, 2019 7:00:42 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelhack] [3.12.2] HazelcastClient 3.12.2 (20190802 - e34b163) is CLIENT_CONNECTED
Oct 23, 2019 7:00:42 AM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelhack] [3.12.2] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Oct 23, 2019 7:00:42 AM com.hazelcast.client.impl.statistics.Statistics
INFO: Client statistics is enabled with period 3 seconds.
Data....: 9999999999
Connection Successful!
Now, `map` as one Entity data.
Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class com.bsfi.java.client.SampleHazelObject from other members
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:88)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:77)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:187)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getValue(CachedQueryEntry.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getTargetObject(CachedQueryEntry.java:108)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.extractAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:105)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.getAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:61)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.readAttributeValue(AbstractPredicate.java:145)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.apply(AbstractPredicate.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.PartitionScanRunner.run(PartitionScanRunner.java:101)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.HDPartitionScanExecutor.execute(HDPartitionScanExecutor.java:22)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryRunner.runPartitionIndexOrPartitionScanQueryOnGivenOwnedPartition(QueryRunner.java:192)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.HDQueryPartitionOperation.runInternal(HDQueryPartitionOperation.java:28)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.HDMapOperation.run(HDMapOperation.java:88)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.call(Operation.java:170)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:210)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:199)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:147)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:125)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:110)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(InvocationFuture.java:79)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:155)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.collectResultsFromMissingPartitions(AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.java:260)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.invokeOnMissingPartitions(AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.call(AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.java:99)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractCallableMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractCallableMessageTask.java:35)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:129)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:96)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:33)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:163)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:252)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.invokeWithPredicate(ClientMapProxy.java:1379)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.values(ClientMapProxy.java:1367)
    at com.bsfi.java.client.ErrorDemo.main(ErrorDemo.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class com.bsfi.java.client.SampleHazelObject from other members
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.ClassLocator.tryToGetClassFromRemote(ClassLocator.java:157)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.ClassLocator.handleClassNotFoundException(ClassLocator.java:95)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.UserCodeDeploymentService.handleClassNotFoundException(UserCodeDeploymentService.java:89)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.UserCodeDeploymentClassLoader.loadClass(UserCodeDeploymentClassLoader.java:57)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:288)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:252)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$ClassLoaderAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:699)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:84)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:77)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:187)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getValue(CachedQueryEntry.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getTargetObject(CachedQueryEntry.java:108)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.extractAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:105)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.getAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:61)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.readAttributeValue(AbstractPredicate.java:145)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.apply(AbstractPredicate.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.PartitionScanRunner.run(PartitionScanRunner.java:101)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.HDPartitionScanExecutor.execute(HDPartitionScanExecutor.java:22)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryRunner.runPartitionIndexOrPartitionScanQueryOnGivenOwnedPartition(QueryRunner.java:192)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.HDQueryPartitionOperation.runInternal(HDQueryPartitionOperation.java:28)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.HDMapOperation.run(HDMapOperation.java:88)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.call(Operation.java:170)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:210)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:199)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:147)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:125)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:110)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the code shown references SampleHazelObject, but the log messages indicate it's trying to load HazelObject, which isn't shown or referenced anywhere that I can see.

Is it possible the jar file deployed in the cloud has a different (renamed) version of this class than what is running on the client?

Comment: Sorry, did not make the change on the log for the sample code. Now you can see the log.I have nothing currently deployed on cloud. It runs on a sandbox from Hazelcast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load `com.bsfi.java.client.SampleHazelObject` onto the cluster before using map. Use UserCodeDeployment to load the class definition in a running cluster, see here: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.4/manual/html-single/index.html#member-user-code-deployment-beta